# How to create a multiple part in a same model in abaqus using abaqus script

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, text, python-import

```
from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from optimization import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

fd =open('circle_input.txt','r')
d=np.loadtxt(fd,delimiter=',',dtype={'names':('co1','col2','col3'),'formats':('float','float','float')})
for i in range(0,len(d),1):

    Description = 'As particles: '# + 'X = ' + str(x) + ' Y = ' + str(y) + ' Z = ' + str(z)
    Model = 'Model' 
    print Description
    print Model
    mdb.Model(modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT, name=Model, description=Description)

    for j in range(i+1,len(d)): 
    ## Sketch a square
        mdb.models[Model].ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=200.0)
        mdb.models[Model].sketches['__profile__'].CircleByCenterPerimeter(center=(d[i][0], d[i][1]), point1=(0.0, d[i][2]))            
        mdb.models[Model].Part(dimensionality=TWO_D_PLANAR, name='Part-1', type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)
        mdb.models[Model].parts['Part-1'].BaseShell(sketch=mdb.models[Model].sketches['__profile__'])
        del mdb.models[Model].sketches['__profile__']
```

i am trying to draw multiple circles in the same model from imported text file.
where each row specifies the geometric information precisely the circle center and radius.

The following code I wrote but it is only sketching the one circle

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create your part outside of the loop.   This code has not been tested.

```
from part import *
from material import *
from section import *
from assembly import *
from step import *
from interaction import *
from load import *
from mesh import *
from optimization import *
from job import *
from sketch import *
from visualization import *
from connectorBehavior import *
import numpy as np
from math import sqrt

fd =open('circle_input.txt','r')
d=np.loadtxt(fd,delimiter=',',dtype={'names':('co1','col2','col3'),'formats':('float','float','float')})
for i in range(0,len(d),1):

    Description = 'As particles: '# + 'X = ' + str(x) + ' Y = ' + str(y) + ' Z = ' + str(z)
    Model = 'Model' 
    print Description
    print Model
    model = mdb.Model(modelType=STANDARD_EXPLICIT, name=Model, description=Description)
    sketch = model.ConstrainedSketch(name='__profile__', sheetSize=200.0)
    part = model.Part(dimensionality=TWO_D_PLANAR, name='Part-1', type=DEFORMABLE_BODY)  

    for j in range(i+1,len(d)): 
    ## Sketch a square            
        sketch.CircleByCenterPerimeter(center=(d[i][0], d[i][1]), point1=(0.0, d[i][2]))            

    part.BaseShell(sketch=sketch)
    del model.sketches['__profile__']
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks above code is tested and it's working...If I want  to mesh all the parts with the same meshing, Is it fair to add those meshing lines in the above mentioned loop..i tried this but it gives me indentation error

Comment: if you have parts that are the same (same mesh) you likely should just have one part, with many instances.